# programatiically creating views strong properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

Previously I've been creating my views with interface builder.

When creating views with storyboards or nibs I would connect my outlets. I understand that the outlets are creating a strong connection to the properties on the view.

If I am creating views programmatically should my properties be strong?

.h

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *loginView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *usernameTextField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *passwordTextField;

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *signInButton;

@end
```

.m

```
@interface LoginViewController ()

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (void)initViewsAndLayout
{
   _loginView = [[UIView alloc] init];
   _loginView.frame = self.view.bounds;
   [self.view addSubview:_loginView];

   //...
}
@end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things:

1. Your code isn't using the properties you defined
2. Don't put the private properties in the .h file
3. Don't state that your class conforms to the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol in the .h file

As for whether the properties should be `strong` or `weak` I prefer `strong` but since you will be adding each of these properties (views) to the view controller's view, it would be fine to make them `weak` since there will always be a reference to them as long as the view controller is alive.

Your .h should just be:

```
@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController
@end
```

Your .m should be (assuming you do want to use the properties):

```
@interface LoginViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *loginView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *usernameTextField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UITextField *passwordTextField;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIButton *signInButton;

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (void)initViewsAndLayout
{
   self.loginView = [[UIView alloc] init];
   self.loginView.frame = self.view.bounds;
   [self.view addSubview:self.loginView];

   //...
}

@end
```

Comment: Thank you for the explaination!

Answer (score 1):

When you use the strong attribute, you are basically writing `retain`, as in, you want Objective-C to allocate memory for the property and hold it until it is released.

That is all strong means.

This is only necessary if you are using ARC (though you can still use retain in ARC). If not, use retain.

> "If I am creating views programmatically should my properties be strong?"

If they are objects and not primitives, then yes.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to make properties with strong attribute if you want to create it manually not to use xib or storyboard.

As your code in `initViewsAndLayout`, if you always create a subview and add it to a view of a viewcontroller simultaneously in same method scope, there is no problem even if you use weak or assign attribute. `addSubview` will increase a reference count of the subview. But, I don't think it's such a good habit because all of us could make a mistake.

Therefore, you had better make a property of UIView with strong attribute.

Answer (score 1):

As a simple rule of thumb,

1. Any view is always owned (maintained by strong reference) by its
   superview, when they are added to the superview.
2. A top-level view is always owned (maintained by strong reference) by its VC.

Now, a view can be added to its superview in two different ways,

- When a view is created from code and added to some superview using `addSubview:` method. (This is what your question suggest).
- When the view hierarchy is loaded from a nib file. (Here also implicit `addSubview:` calls are made by UIKit to create the hierarchy) and thus subviews are retained by strong reference their respective superviews.

So in either cases views are implicitly retained by their superviews and thus never get disposed until/unless the top-level view gets disposed by itself. So declaring `strong` properties for subviews imposes another ownership on the subviews:

- An implicit ownership by its superview, and
- An explicitly ownership by the property.

So in general, declaring `strong` property for subviews are not required, however it has been created (from nib / by code).

However, under some special situation declaring `strong` properties for views might be required. For example, when a view should be removed and re-added to its superview, the view should be declared as strong. When such a view is removed from its superview, the superview releases its ownership as well. So if we need to maintain a strong reference of that view if we need to reassign the same view again to some superview. In that case, a `strong` property reference to the view becomes handy and it disallows the view to be released.

---

PS:

> When creating views with storyboards or nibs I would connect my
>   outlets. I understand that the outlets are creating a strong
>   connection to the properties on the view.

I found that there's merely a misconception, in your question. When creating view from storyboard/nib, outlets does not create any so-called `strong` connection with the properties. `IBOutlet`s only describe how a property loads a view. In case of an outlet property, the view pointed by the property is unarchived and loaded if it has not already been loaded. However, its retention still depends on the `strong`/`weak` property accessor.

Comment: +1 I think you and I both had the same reaction to these earlier answers!

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> If I am creating views programmatically should my properties be `strong`?

Two part answer:

1. The view controller should definite maintain a `strong` reference to its top level view.

   When not using NIBs or storyboards at all and doing everything programmatically, the root view is instantiated in `loadView` and generally stored in a `retain`/`strong` property. `UIViewController` already has a `view` property that bears the `retain` memory semantics, thats generally used. (For more information about programmatically created views, see the [Creating a View Programmatically](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ViewLoadingandUnloading/ViewLoadingandUnloading.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH10-SW36) section in the *Resource Management in View Controllers* chapter of the *View Controller Programming Guide for iOS*)

   (If you're not creating the root view in `loadView` and are instead instantiating the root view with a NIB or storyboard and are only programmatically creating the subviews, don't worry about the above discussion, as the NIB/storyboard takes care of all of that for you.)
2. For the subviews, when you call `addSubview`, the view is retained by its parent view. It's unnecessary for the view controller to also maintain `strong` reference to it as well. You can, but it is not necessary.

   In my mind, the view owns its subviews, not the view controller. If one of these subviews is removed from its parent view, I don't think the view controller should be retaining it and it doesn't seem like good design that I have to remember to `nil` the property in the view controller, too. Worse, if I remove a container view that has nested subviews, I don't want to have to manually keep track of setting all of those individual properties in the view controller that I have to `nil`, as well.

   Don't get me wrong: You can use `strong` with the subviews if you want/need. But I think it's incorrect to imply that it's ill-advised to use `weak`.